# Images are not coming in phone gap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, windows-phone-7, cordova

I have installed SDK of phone gap in visual studio 2010..I have done small application using HTML5 and JavaScript. in design part of html file ,i am able to see images , when i run the application in emulator images are coming blank, but if i open file with browser like  Mozilla etc.. images are coming proper manner. please any one help me...why images are not coming in emulator.

Comment: I don't know why this one is closed as I'm also currently facing the same problem. Any how +1 from me for the question.

Comment: For me it seems that only JPG images are working. So I converted all images to jpg format, and it started working. Hope this would helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the build action of the images to `Content`?

You also need to set the path correctly and ensure you've added the new image to `GapSourceDictionary.xml`.

Comment: ya i have set the build action of the images to Content instead of resource....still i am not getting any images...please any one help me..Thank you

Comment: <CordovaSourceDictionary>
    <FilePath Value="www\Images\2- untitled.png"/> 
</CordovaSourceDictionary>                                           
i have set path correctly as shown above code in GapSourceDictionary.xml file. and also i have set build action of images in property window is content...but images are not coming...please help me how to show images in phone gap windows phone emulator...thank you

Comment: @user1177921 please update your question to include a repro